# Read a line of text and set it as a variable for a batch file

Tags: windows, command-line-tool

I want to put a date/time in a line in a text file then have my batch file use that date to compare against the current date/time. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define a windows variable from text in a file:

```
set MYVAR= type abc.txt
```

`set` is used to tell the computer to set a variable called my var and `type abc.txt` is the command to read a files contents.